# How can I handle deleting an item from list through a modal rendered in the layout(top level)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am rendering my modal in my layout and the modal's functionality is to delete a list item in my todo list. How can I pass that handle delete function to the modal?

```
class TODO extends Component {

    handleDelete = (id) => {
     const newArr = this.state.TODOList.filter((item, idx) => {id !== 
    idx})
    this.setState({ TODOList: newArr }); 
    }

    render () {
      return this.state.TODOList.map((item, id) =>
            <div>
              <ITEMS
                idx={id}
                id={id}
              />
             </div>
         )
      }
}

class myModal extends Component {

    render () {
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={...???....}> Delete </Button>
        </div>
     )
    }
}

class Layout extends Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <div>
          <myModal />
         </div>
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: Which `id` you want to delete. I mean which id will be passed from myModal?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to include my ITEM component.. It is used to render individual items in my TODO component. So that ID is referring to an ITEM id. I will edit that in my code above.

Comment: I mean when the `myModal` will be clicked. How will you access the `id` which has to be deleted in `myModal`

Comment: Ah. That was part of my question. I am not sure how to pass data up to myModal, since it is part of my layout, with my current setup. And if there is a better approach.

Comment: there is one modal. When you click it which item of the list will be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function down as props

```
class TodoList extends Component {
    constructor () {
      this.setState({ TODOList: [...] })
    }
    handleDelete = (id) => {
     const newArr = this.state.TODOList.filter((item, idx) => {id !== 
    idx})
    this.setState({ TODOList: newArr }); 
    }
    render() {
       return (
         <div className="container">
            { return this.TODOList.map(todo, idx => { <TODO idx={idx} /> }) }
         <Modal handleDelete={this.handleDelete} />
         </div>
       )
    }
}

class myModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
    }
    render () {
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(this.idx)}> Delete </Button>
        </div>
     )
    }
}

class Layout extends Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <div>
          <myModal handleDelete={this.handleDelete} />
         </div>
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: My TODO component is a child of my Layout component. It is alright to pass my handleDelete up to layout?

Comment: it's best to have a container component called TodoList and keep your list in that component. then you could pass data down to both your modal and your TODO from the TODOList component.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add `<TODO>` as **child of `<Layout>`**. You can set its `ref='todo'`.Create a `handleDelete` in `<Layout>`. Call the `handleDelete` of todo using its `ref`. And pass `handleDelete` in props of `<myModal>`. This is for the case when you want to have a state for `TODO`

```
class TODO extends Component {
    handleDelete = (id) => {
        const newArr = this.state.TODOList.filter((item, idx) => {id !==idx})
        this.setState({ TODOList: newArr }); 
    }
}  
class myModal extends Component {
    state = {idToDelete : 2}
    render () {
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.handleDelete(this.state.idToDelete)}> Delete </Button>
        </div>
     )
     }
}
class Layout extends Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <div>
          <myModal handleDelete={handleDelete} />
          <TODO ref="todo" />
         </div>
      )
    }
    handleDelete = (id) =>{
        this.refs.handleDelete(id);
    }

}
```